# The difference between a UIWindow and a UIView

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

After creating a blank xib file, it seems that we can either drag a UIWindow or UIView to cover the entire screen.  My question is what are the practical differences between the two and in what circumstances that we should use one over the other?

Comment: How can we drag a UIWindow to a blank `.xib` file? I'm unable to do so in Xcode.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Windows do not have any visible content themselves but provide a basic container for your application’s views. Views define a portion of a window that you want to fill with some content. Typically, there is only one window in an iOS application.

[About Windows and Views](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503)

Comment: Another way of thinking of this is that a window can never have a superview. It's the thing that sits at the top of the view hierarchy.

Comment: Technically a window *doesn't* cover the entire screen. The window's *view* does. So think of a `UIView` as controlling part of the screen: drawing to it etc. A window is a mere container.

Comment: The window *does* cover the entire screen (usually), the window is the root view in the view hierarchy (it is a UIView subclass). Doc: "When creating windows in Interface Builder, it is recommended that you enable the Full Screen at Launch option in the attributes inspector. If this option is not enabled and your window is not sized properly for the target device, touch events may not be received by some of your views. This is because the window does not receive touch events outside of its bounds and views are not clipped to the window’s bounds by default."

Comment: @beryllium As you said, "Windows do not have any visible content". Then what does this mean? `self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];` How can it get something to show on its own?

Answer (score 9):

It's not an either/or kind of thing. Your app must have a UIWindow instance that is the container for the UIView instances you present.

An app can either load the UIWindow instance from a nib file, or it can create it programmatically. Look at some sample code to see how it is done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is it true that there should only be one UIWindow for each project ?

Comment: @Stanley usually that is the case, yes. However it is not mandatory but just common.

Comment: One case where you have two is when you want to handle an external screen, for example.